# Adobe Illustrator - Convert .jpg with gradient background to vector object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, jpg

I don't have too much experience with Adobe Illustrator (I am a beginner), but what I am trying to do is to convert a logo (see attached image - .jpg format) to vector object in Adobe Illustrator.

Is there a way to do that without color distortion ?

I have tried with **Image Trace - High Fidelity Photo option - 100% colors** but the result does not look good (color distortion - see another image) , also I have tried to find which font is used with font finder online tool, but is seems to be premium font and idea was to rewrite the letters with black colors, and later to recolor the letter(s) with gradient color.

What do you think, please give me advice. Thank you in advance

[image: Logo]
[image: Second image]
[image: Third image]

Comment: Trace it as black and white and increase the threshold. Then you can colour the solid black text with gradients.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. Do you have some example or tutorial please ?

Comment: Search youtube for "Illustrator gradient tool tutorial"

Comment: Image tracing and gradients are basic AI features and are well documented online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the jpg in a **raster** image editor (i.e. Photoshop) and covert it to greyscale, then adjust the image levels to achieve a standard black and white image.

[image]

Save the black and white version and trace **that** image in Illustrator.

And then reapply gradients and color....

[image]